# the question of rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node

Tags: ros, turtlesim, rosrun, turtlesim-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

strong textwhen i input  rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node in terminal, it displays that [ERROR] [1352970963.999973192]: [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at [localemphasized texthost:11311].  Retrying...
what's the matter? thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48347/the-question-of-rosrun-turtlesim-turtlesim_node/) by [asher](https://answers.ros.org/users/3598/asher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, try runing

```
roscore
```

in a different terminal

---

Originally posted by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) with karma: 172 on 2012-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1